# Assigning a child to a parent

Tags: c++, pointers, upcasting

I have a problem assigning a child pointer to a parent one. Here is the example:

```
class A() {};
class B() : public A {};
class C() {

    B* b;
    C() { b = new B(); }        
    B* GetB() { return b; }
}

C* c = new C();
A* a = c->GetB(); //compilation error
```

Why is it happening? If I write this:

```
A* a = (A*)c->GetB();
```

then it works, but I want to know why this is happening.

This is just an example, I can't reveal the real code, so if you find a syntax error, it's because I have just written it. Thanks!

EDIT:
My editor is telling me that: "a value of type B* cannot be assigned to an entity of type A*". What does this mean?

Comment: Have you actually taken your little example and compiled it? I'm pretty sure it would work and you didn't faithfully reproduce the actual problem. Also, knowing the compiler error message would be useful.

Comment: Yeah, just thought the same thing. That code as it is should work fine.

Comment: Agreed. Same opinion.

Comment: Your current example contains an access control issue in that all of C's members are private so the example code can't access them, but I doubt that's the issue you're interested in.

Comment: Isnt the default access specifier private? I believe it will even fail at `C* c = new C();`

Comment: Post some code that reproduces the problem and isn't full of errors.

Comment: I don't know why you are complaining about mistakes that are not related with the problem. Ok, I forgot the public access control, and what? That is not the problem, the problem is about upcasting with a return value.

Comment: We are complaining because there is no way of figuring out what the problem is from the code you posted. Make an effort if you want people to help.

Comment: @Frion3L: We're complaining because (a) we can't compile your code to investigate because it's full of errors unrelated to the question and (b) when we fix those errors we don't see the problem you're reporting. Could you post some code that reproduces the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

> This is just an example, I can't reveal the real code, so if you find a syntax error, it's because I have just written it. Thanks!

You should not be too lazy to provide a **correct** example that actually resembles your problem. 
I don't get any compilations errors using the correct C++ Syntax with your example in MSVC 2012.

```
class A // why () ?!
{ 
};

class B : public A 
{ 
};

class C 
{
private:
    B* b;
public: // missing 
    C (void) : b(new B) { }
    B * get_b() { return b; }
}; // missing ";"


int main(void)
{
  C* c = new C;
  A* a = c->get_b(); // no compilation error
  return 0;
}
```

Why your editor tells you that you can't assign is not really obvious since you didn't tell us which editor you're using.